# Dictionary keys contain carriage return - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, carriage-return

I have an dictionary in Python script. I can't get any value by given key because `dict.get(key)` returns None.

So I printed those keys of the dict and **print** returned this text: `[u'2\r', u'G\r', u'\\\r', u'q\r', u'%\r', ' ', u'O\r', u'd\r', u'y\r', u'-\r', u'B\r', u'W\r', u'l\r', u'5\r', u'J\r', u'_\r', u't\r', u'(\r'.......]`

I'm curious whether it is ok if each key contains carriage return. I can't find out why is it there.

The code of filling dict:

```
prevChar = ' '
        self.saDictA[' ']=[]
        for i in range(0,len(self.saA)):
            currentChar = self.stringA[self.saA[i]]
            if currentChar == prevChar:
                self.saDictA[prevChar].append(i)
            else:
                self.saDictA[currentChar]=[i]
                prevChar = currentChar
```

As you can see in the code above each key should be one single char so I don't understand why the keys contain '\r' signs.

EDIT: I tried to check len of each key in dict before saving it and then after loading it. I've realized that before saving this lib, each key has length equal to 1 but after load, each key has length 2.

Here is the code:

```
import cPickle as pickle

def ssaDictA():
        for i in self.creation.saDictA.keys():
            print len(i)
        with open('saDictA','w+') as f:
            pickle.dump(self.creation.saDictA,f)
```

OUTPUT:
1
1
1
...
1

```
def lsaDictA():
        with open('saDictA','rb') as f:
            dict = pickle.load(f)
        for i in dict.keys():
            print len(i)
        return dict
```

OUTPUT:
2
2
2
...
2

pickle is cPickle - import cPickle as pickle
Where could be the problem?

Comment: Unsure the problem is there. I did : `>>> k = u'a\r\n'
>>> print k,k`
`a

a

`
`>>> k
u'a\r\n'
>>> d[k] = 'foo'
>>> d.get(k)
'foo'
>>>` 

with no error.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm sorry for misunderstood, It returns None object not Error. Error returns len(dict.get(key)) because it's None.

Comment: Without knowing more, I would say the problem lies somewhere in `self.suffixArrayA` or `self.stringA` ...

Comment: when you add a key to the dictionary try using the srings strip() method to remove the carrige returns.

Comment: @Yoriz It did not help. But I realized that it could be the problem with pickle.dump or load as I wrote above in edit.

Comment: You open the file in binary more for reading but not for writing, and you get unexpected `\r` after reading back. Hmm ... Try to read and write always in binary mode.